# Error when using unwind segue with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller, unwind-segue

I have a Navigation Controller with a UITableViewController.

When a user selects a cell on the TableViewController, it pushes to a new View Controller with a Table View inside. The user then selects a cell and the data gets passed back via an unwind segue.

The problem is I get this error when using a search bar before selecting the cell. Here is what the console says:

```
popToViewController:transition: called on <UINavigationController 0x7fc8ab856e00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
```

Code from View Controller I'm unwinding **from**:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MonsterSpriteCell
        let monster = monsters[indexPath.row]
        selectedMonster = monster
        if isTeamBuilding {
            // **ERROR OCCURS HERE**
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveToTeamBuilderTableVC", sender: cell)
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMonsterDetail", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Here is the link the the project. The View Controller I'm unwinding from is Browse View Controller. The View Controller I'm unwinding to is TeamBuilderViewController
https://github.com/emanleet/monsterpedia

EDIT: I think it might be relevant to note that the segue unwinds to TeamBuilderTableViewController, which is a View Controller that is inside a container as a part of another view controller. Does anyone know if this might be why my unwind segue isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SearchController is presenting an empty view controller
If you print the `presentedViewController` in `didSelectRow..` when the search is active you will see a view controller.
that means you’re trying to perform segue from under the current presentation. You should dismiss the `SearchController` before performing any segues or presentations.

Also in this case you don’t need a `SearchController` since you’re only using the `SearchBar` for filtering.
Instead, put a `SearchBar` in the `tableViewHeaderView` and use its delegate to do the filtering and instead of checking if `isActive` to access the complete list vs. the filtered results, just put the whole array in the filter when the text is cleared and always access the filtered results.

Answer (score 2):

Two step thing, first dismiss the search controller presented view controller, then, do your thing.

```
yourSearchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { 
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourUnwindSegue", sender: self)
            })
```

Comment: This worked for me thanks. Until I tried this verbatim, it wasn't obvious that this code works whether `presentedViewController` equals `yourSearchController` or is `nil`.